# Использование yield в присваивании

Tags: python, yield

Читая чужой код наткнулся на строчку вида:

```
x = yield foo(a, b, c)
```

Я первый раз сталкиваюсь с таким использованием `yield`.
Что происходит в этом коде? Что именно будет записано в переменную `x`?

UPD: Если это важно, то foo возвращает объект типа tornado.concurrent.Future

Comment: @Danis В `x` абсолютно точно будет не None, т.к. далее по коду выполняются обращения к его атрибутам (x.value) и этот код работает в проде.

Comment: А дальше что там с `x` происходит, интересно?

Comment: Хотелось бы увидеть больше кода в контексте, как-то это странно

Comment: Вызов функции с yield'ами создаёт объект-генератор, а у генераторов есть метод `send` принимающий один аргумент, и этот аргумент как раз и попадает в yield